# Gnome terminal is not working properly

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm new to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My problem is described below.

My terminal prompt is the `$` sign only. It's not showing like `kaushik-kaushik-pc -$`.

My second problem is that when I try to become the super user by `sudo su`, it prompts for my password but after that, it shows `Authentication Fail`.

When I'm trying to use previous commands by using the <kbd>↑</kbd> key, it prints this `^[[a`, nor does it work for the <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> keys.

Comment: I have also experienced that but in a guest account, check to make sure you are using an account with privilege.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: We need more information: please edit your question and show us the output of `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering only the authentication question.

`sudo su` is completely unnecessary.

For a single command (like `cat /etc/shadow`) you  just type `sudo cat /etc/shadow` and then you  give **your own** password. This will by default only be possible for the *first user* (the one created during installation).

If you are really convinced that you need a real **root shell** then type `sudo -i`, run the commands you need and don't forget to leave that shell again by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: When i'm typing 'sudo -i' it is giving an error message:
sudo: /bin/bash: command not found.